# Display whole number decimal data type to 1dp

Tags: c#

I have code which I want to return each of those values to 1 dp:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        decimal[] engine = { 2, 2.5M, 2.6M, 3 };
        engine = engine.Select(x => { x = Math.Round(x, 1); return x; }).ToArray();
        foreach (var item in engine)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

So it would output something like this in a console application:

```
2.0
2.5
2.6
3.0
```

But the problem is, it outputs:

```
2
2.5
2.6
3
```

How can I make it return whole numbers to 1dp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(item.ToString("F1"));
```

See these links for more format strings:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Comment: +1. Just want to add, thats also possible using String.Format("{0:0.0}" .. which sometimes is a little bit more flexible.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Thanks for the links too! I'll accept it as the answer when I'm allowed too.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below code

```
Console.WriteLine(item.ToString("0.0"));
```

Comment: Instead of just telling him what code to use, it would be helpful if you explained your solution.

Comment: The above code will format the value in the 'item' with one decimal point. If you need two dp then you can use 0.00

Comment: I'm sure this would work too, I just used the code from the first answer and it worked, thanks!